# Count and Update

Tags: php, mysql

I've got a table-A which contains 2 colunms (Student, Grade). How do I get the `COUNT` of the the students who have 'A' grades?

I've got another table called table-B. How do I update the colunm named `semester2` using the previous result (number of students with an 'A' grade).

```
$query = "SELECT grade,COUNT(A) FROM table-A WHERE subject = 'Science'";
mysql_query("UPDATE table-B SET semester2 = ?? WHERE subject = 'Science' LIMIT 1");
```

Comment: First you say that `table-A` has 2 columns `(Student, Grade)` and then use use `subject` column in your SQL.

Comment: Thanks. I want to count the number of grandes for each subject and then update table -B with the relevant count for each subject.

Answer (score 0):

you could use

```
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM table-A WHERE Grade = 'A'
```

and

```
UPDATE table-B SET semester2 = (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM table-A WHERE Grade = 'A')
```

Comment: Thanks. Will this single line do the trick? (get the count of A's for science from table-A and update table-B's science colunm with the count result) mysql_query("UPDATE table-B SET semester2 = (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM table-A WHERE Grade = 'A' && Subject = 'Science') WHERE Subject ='Science' LIMIT 1");

Comment: it should, just try it!

Comment: what does it do with  COUNT(1) ? why can't it be COUNT ('A')?

Comment: 1 means that you have to add one for every line in the selection that is made with the WHERE clause

Comment: @NathaliaZeed if my answer is correct, can you please upvote it and accept it as a solution?